# How can I make a link to a local file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to make an `href` link that should open an html file that is saved locally.
normally if its not locally I would make a new route that call the `index` function in a controller that I would create and this index function would return a blade.
Now What would be the difference if I want to link a local file?

Comment: Is your server running on the same machine?

Comment: Now yes I'm running the app locally

Comment: Open the file in your browser and you should get the URL to that file.

Comment: I think I should just include the path of the file and that should do it right? because I did so but I'm not getting the file I want I'm being redirected to a "about:blank#blocked" route so since I'm using an already developped platform, do you think this is because of a middleware or something blocking route like that?

Comment: That might be because browsers block links from "localhost" to a local file. Why not copy that file to your app?

Comment: that file is launcher for an Elearning course made with xAPI protocoll that I'm trying to launch from the app, so the link should launch this course

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. But you have to put that html file in `public folder` in your project.

Assume you put `hello.html` in folder `your_project/public/welcome`,

Then the link will be `url('/welcome/hello.html')`

No need route or controller

Comment: thanks for your response, what if I cant include that file in my app? because the file is html file that launches an xAPI eLearning course so it should run in its directory because it has a lot of js files and some dependencies in the same directory.